# Overhead of temporary std::tuple in init statement

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple

I am playing around with `std::tuple`s in various contexts and came across some things that are working, but I am unsure whether they have a performance penalty.

In C++17 an init statement has been introduced for `if` and `switch` statements. In order to define multiple variables of different types, you can use a temporary tuple and structured bindings.

```
if(const auto& [x, y] = std::tuple{some_expensive_int_calculation(), get_string_message()}; x != 0 && y != "") {
    std::cout << "X is " << x << ", message equals " << y << std::endl;
}
```

This *should* not have a large performance penalty, if any. Of course it would create a tuple which itself needs a bit of memory more than the types itself, but this is allocated on the stack, so again, it shouldn't really hurt that much. The bindings `x` and `y` are resolved at compile time and not at runtime, so this seems like a solution which doesn't have a large runtime penalty, does it?

**EDIT**: Updated the example to prevent the compiler from optimising the tuple away trivially and making the problem more clear.

Comment: You can always test it with your compiler. For example, here's a modified version: https://godbolt.org/g/uEwYSm

Comment: It often helps to have both versions of the function so you can compare assembly: https://godbolt.org/g/Gfyi5R

Comment: This question cannot be answered in absolute terms, because "large" is a relative category. The same exact number of additional microseconds could ruin the performance of an algorithm, or go completely unnoticed.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight While that is true, I believe this question can be answered. The question almost answers itself, though: it *should* not have a large performance penalty. It is a zero-overhead abstraction for simple cases, but it's possible that this could add a bit of overhead for more complex cases.

Comment: Easiest is to try it with a type like `struct A{A();A(A const&);A(A&&);~A();A&operator=(A const&);A&operator=(A&&);};`, which will make it obvious in the generated code that you get an extra move-construction and destruction using your tuple compared to using 2 separate variables. Whether that's "large" depends on your type and usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the given example, it's fairly trivial for the compiler to prove that not assigning to, or allocating storage for, `x` has the same outcome as assigning to and testing `x`. Therefore with optimisations enabled I would expect it to elide any mention of `x` in the resulting assembler.

Indeed, with gcc 7.3 `-O2`, the following program:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    if(const auto& [x, y] = std::tuple{0, "Test"}; x == 0) {
        std::cout << y << std::endl;
    }
}
```

becomes:

```
main:
# stack-frame related code
  sub rsp, 8
# get address of "Test" string
  mov esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
# get address of std::cout
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
# call operator <<
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
# move returned ostream reference to rdi (arg1)
  mov rdi, rax
# and call std::endl
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
# return 0
  xor eax, eax
# clean up stack and return
  add rsp, 8
  ret
```

Note that there is no mention of x anywhere in this assembler output. Nor indeed is there any mention of a tuple or a conditional branch.

This is allowed by the "as if" rule.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably should have used another example here, this doesn't really address my question correctly. The compiler does optimise the x away because of this trivial example, but I meant a situation where x is not trivially optimisable, I will update the example with something better.

Comment: @Benedikt the same principle holds. If you write expressive code, the compiler will generally do the optimal thing.